# Stepper Pure HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, stepper

I'm confused about a progress bar that I have created.

I want the progress bar to change its background color to blue after setting the class to “active”. But I want the progress bar to change its background color before the class is set to “active”.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="progressBar">
  <li class="active">Beong Processed</li>
  <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
  <li>Paid</li>
</ul>
```

…and CSS:

```
.progressBar li.active {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
.progressBar li.active:before {
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
.progressBar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

**The result is this**

[image: wrong]

**I want it to be like this**

[image: right]

https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/c69e374r/2/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `.progressBar .active:after`
instead of `.progressBar li.active + li:after`

**+ in css**

> It is Adjacent sibling combinator. It combines two sequences of simple
>   selectors having the same parent and the second one must come
>   IMMEDIATELY after the first.

```css
.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    background-color: white
}

.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: dodgerblue
}

.progressBar .active:after {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active">Beong Processed</li>
        <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
        <li>Paid</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for mor help

Comment: it work, I understand that's you mean. and thank you so much to explain it

Comment: happy to help:)

Answer (score 7):

According to what you requested, this is more like the answer you asked for?

```css
.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left:none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8.5px auto 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 97%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right:none;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: dodgerblue
}

.progressBar .active:after {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active">Beong Processed</li>
        <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
        <li>Paid</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will suggest to also setting margin and padding to 0 in .progressBar, otherwise the ul is not centered.

Comment: @Vingtoft I'm sure he can figure out that for himself depending on the usecase.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your `.progressBar li.active + li:after` selector to `.progressBar li.active:after`

```css
.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    background-color: white
}

.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: dodgerblue
}

.progressBar li.active:after {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active">Beong Processed</li>
        <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
        <li>Paid</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MuhammadAliDEV What do you mean "is not working"?

Comment: it means "line is not displayed".

Comment: @MuhammadAliDEV The line is displayed when I run the snippet. What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    background-color: white
}

.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    content:"\2713";
    color:white;
}

.progressBar li.active:after {
    background-color: dodgerblue;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active">1st Step Processed</li>
        <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
        <li>Paid</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).